# Code Coverage analysis includes internal Types

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, visual-studio-2015

I have a project that I ran the Visual Studio 2015 code coverage analysis against. In the results, it includes internal classes in the results hierarchy that I can't test against. I don't want to use the `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`, but I also don't like that it's counted as part of the code coverage path.

Is there a way to have visual studio ignore internal classes, so that the code coverage results only includes public classes that I can actually touch with unit tests?

[image: Code Coverage]

The `CachedTypeData` is an internal sealed class with a series of generic methods. As you can above the type is included in my results, right next to two public classes, `Autosave<T>` and `EngineTimer<T>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `Visual studio` doesn't has such a capability however, you can put [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.excludefromcodecoverageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute on your `Internal` classes.

Note: `Visual Studio`'s CCA measures the CC's percentage through the `IL`, if your `Classes under test` use an `Internal` method/class then those `Internal` method/class will be cover.
So in most cases you shouldn't split/exclude your `Internal` classes.

Comment: So if I test the public method that invokes a method on an internal class, it will be considered as part of my code coverage?

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger Yes, it is.

Comment: I've also noticed that my `IDisposable` classes get 100% code coverage at times, despite never actually testing or calling a method that invokes `Dispose()`. I imagine that's a different question though.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger It's a different question and I need more details however I'll explain you how CC works and then you'll be able to find why it happens. CC works as the following: It takes all the dlls in the target directory and build a directed graph G based on the IL code. Based on G it builds all possible directed-path. Execute the tests and mark the relevant paths. Calculate the percentage. Method with 100% CC means you walk through all paths(class with 100% means all methods are 100%). So if you execute the Dispose in at least one of your tests, the 100% coverage is possible.

Comment: I posted [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31757849/1815321) on it. What you explained is what I would expect, but there are other oddities I'm experiencing.