# Code Coverage analysis shows 100% coverage when most of the class is missing coverage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage, visual-studio-2015

I have a class  that implements the IDisposable interface.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/// <summary>
/// <para>
/// The Engine Timer allows for starting a timer that will execute a callback at a given interval.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// The timer may fire:
///  - infinitely at the given interval
///  - fire once
///  - fire _n_ number of times.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// The Engine Timer will stop its self when it is disposed of.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// The Timer requires you to provide it an instance that will have an operation performed against it.
/// The callback will be given the generic instance at each interval fired.
/// </para>
/// <para>
/// In the following example, the timer is given an instance of an IPlayer. 
/// It starts the timer off with a 30 second delay before firing the callback for the first time.
/// It tells the timer to fire every 60 seconds with 0 as the number of times to fire. When 0 is provided, it will run infinitely.
/// Lastly, it is given a callback, which will save the player every 60 seconds.
/// @code
/// var timer = new EngineTimer<IPlayer>(new DefaultPlayer());
/// timer.StartAsync(30000, 6000, 0, (player, timer) => player.Save());
/// @endcode
/// </para>
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type that will be provided when the timer callback is invoked.</typeparam>
public sealed class EngineTimer<T> : CancellationTokenSource, IDisposable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The timer task
    /// </summary>
    private Task timerTask;

    /// <summary>
    /// How many times we have fired the timer thus far.
    /// </summary>
    private long fireCount = 0;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EngineTimer{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="callback">The callback.</param>
    /// <param name="state">The state.</param>
    public EngineTimer(T state)
    {
        if (state == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(state), "EngineTimer constructor requires a non-null argument.");
        }

        this.StateData = state;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the object that was provided to the timer when it was instanced.
    /// This object will be provided to the callback at each interval when fired.
    /// </summary>
    public T StateData { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the engine timer is currently running.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsRunning { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// <para>
    /// Starts the timer, firing a synchronous callback at each interval specified until `numberOfFires` has been reached.
    /// If `numberOfFires` is 0, then the callback will be called indefinitely until the timer is manually stopped.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// The following example shows how to start a timer, providing it a callback.
    /// </para>
    /// @code
    /// var timer = new EngineTimer<IPlayer>(new DefaultPlayer());
    /// double startDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds;
    /// double interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalMilliseconds;
    /// int numberOfFires = 0;
    /// 
    /// timer.Start(
    ///     startDelay, 
    ///     interval, 
    ///     numberOfFires, 
    ///     (player, timer) => player.Save());
    /// @endcode
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDelay">
    /// <para>
    /// The `startDelay` is used to specify how much time must pass before the timer can invoke the callback for the first time.
    /// If 0 is provided, then the callback will be invoked immediately upon starting the timer.
    /// </para>
    /// <para>
    /// The `startDelay` is measured in milliseconds.
    /// </para>
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="interval">The interval in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfFires">Specifies the number of times to invoke the timer callback when the interval is reached. Set to 0 for infinite.</param>
    public void Start(double startDelay, double interval, int numberOfFires, Action<T, EngineTimer<T>> callback)
    {
        this.IsRunning = true;

        this.timerTask = Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startDelay), this.Token)
            .ContinueWith(
                (task, state) => RunTimer(task, (Tuple<Action<T, EngineTimer<T>>, T>)state, interval, numberOfFires),
                Tuple.Create(callback, this.StateData),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the specified start delay.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDelay">The start delay in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="interval">The interval in milliseconds.</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfFires">Specifies the number of times to invoke the timer callback when the interval is reached. Set to 0 for infinite.</param>
    public void StartAsync(double startDelay, double interval, int numberOfFires, Func<T, EngineTimer<T>, Task> callback)
    {
        this.IsRunning = true;

        this.timerTask = Task
            .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startDelay), this.Token)
            .ContinueWith(
                async (task, state) => await RunTimerAsync(task, (Tuple<Func<T, EngineTimer<T>, Task>, T>)state, interval, numberOfFires),
                Tuple.Create(callback, this.StateData),
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the timer for this instance.
    /// Stopping the timer will not dispose of the EngineTimer, allowing you to restart the timer if you need to.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        if (!this.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            this.Cancel();
        } 
        this.IsRunning = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stops the timer and releases the unmanaged resources used by the <see cref="T:System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource" /> class and optionally releases the managed resources.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true to release both managed and unmanaged resources; false to release only unmanaged resources.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            this.IsRunning = false;
            this.Cancel();
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private async Task RunTimer(Task task, Tuple<Action<T, EngineTimer<T>>, T> state, double interval, int numberOfFires)
    {
        while (!this.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Only increment if we are supposed to.
            if (numberOfFires > 0)
            {
                this.fireCount++;
            }

            state.Item1(state.Item2, this);
            await PerformTimerCancellationCheck(interval, numberOfFires);
        }
    }

    private async Task RunTimerAsync(Task task, Tuple<Func<T, EngineTimer<T>, Task>, T> state, double interval, int numberOfFires)
    {
        while (!this.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Only increment if we are supposed to.
            if (numberOfFires > 0)
            {
                this.fireCount++;
            }

            await state.Item1(state.Item2, this);
            await PerformTimerCancellationCheck(interval, numberOfFires);
        }
    }

    private async Task PerformTimerCancellationCheck(double interval, int numberOfFires)
    {
        // If we have reached our fire count, stop. If set to 0 then we fire until manually stopped.
        if (numberOfFires > 0 && this.fireCount >= numberOfFires)
        {
            this.Stop();
        }

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(interval), this.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

I then created a series of unit tests for the class.

```
[TestClass]
public class EngineTimerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("MudDesigner")]
    [TestCategory("Engine")]
    [TestCategory("Engine Core")]
    [Owner("Johnathon Sullinger")]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
    public void Exception_thrown_with_null_ctor_argument()
    {
        // Act
        new EngineTimer<ComponentFixture>(null);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("MudDesigner")]
    [TestCategory("Engine")]
    [TestCategory("Engine Core")]
    [Owner("Johnathon Sullinger")]
    public void Ctor_sets_state_property()
    {
        // Arrange
        var fixture = new ComponentFixture();

        // Act
        var engineTimer = new EngineTimer<ComponentFixture>(fixture);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(engineTimer.StateData, "State was not assigned from the constructor.");
        Assert.AreEqual(fixture, engineTimer.StateData, "An incorrect State object was assigned to the timer.");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("MudDesigner")]
    [TestCategory("Engine")]
    [TestCategory("Engine Core")]
    [Owner("Johnathon Sullinger")]
    public void Start_sets_is_running()
    {
        // Arrange
        var fixture = new ComponentFixture();
        var engineTimer = new EngineTimer<ComponentFixture>(fixture);

        // Act
        engineTimer.Start(0, 1, 0, (component, timer) => { });

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(engineTimer.IsRunning, "Engine Timer was not started.");
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("MudDesigner")]
    [TestCategory("Engine")]
    [TestCategory("Engine Core")]
    [Owner("Johnathon Sullinger")]
    public void Callback_invoked_when_running()
    {
        // Arrange
        var fixture = new ComponentFixture();
        var engineTimer = new EngineTimer<ComponentFixture>(fixture);
        bool callbackInvoked = false;

        // Act
        engineTimer.Start(0, 1, 0, (component, timer) => { callbackInvoked = true; });
        Task.Delay(20);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(callbackInvoked, "Engine Timer did not invoke the callback as expected.");
    }
}
```

When I run the unit test coverage analysis in Visual Studio 2015, it tells me that the class is 100% covered by unit tests. However, I've only tested the constructor and the `Start()` method. None of the unit tests touch the `Stop()`, `StartAsync()` or `Dispose()` methods.

Why would Visual Studio tell me I am at 100% code coverage?

[image: Code Coverage]

**Update**

I turned on coverage highlights and discovered that the `Stop()` method is not covered (if I read [this right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159523.aspx)).

[image: Coverage]

It is interesting that the analysis tells me it's 100% covered, even though the coverage highlights shows that it's not included in any unit test paths.

Comment: I executed your code locally and I got a different CC results. Are you sure you executed only the above 4 tests? One more thing, make sure you are on the right CC's result in the combobox.

Comment: I just ran all of the tests. Shouldn't it see that there are blocks not covered, as shown by the highlights, and give me a result of less than 100%?

Comment: It should, does your project has more tests then those 4? When I ran your code snippet the CC of `Stop()`, `Dispose()` and `StartAsync()` were 0% as expected...

Comment: Interesting. I have 80ish total tests. I guess it never dawned on me that the classes being tested by my other tests use this timer class. That's probably why it's at 100%. That makes more sense to me

Comment: I post an answer with step to detect the reason....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to explain the way code coverage works is as the following:

1. Take all dlls from the target directory and build a directed graph `G` based on the `IL code`.
2. Use `G` and creates all possible directed-paths.
3. Execute the tests and mark the relevant paths.
4. Calculate the percentage.

Methods with 100% code coverage means you walk through all the method's paths, during your `UT`'s execution.(Basically the tool doesn't know which class in under test in the `UT`)

Based on the above description the CC's behavior you've faced could happened from at least one of the following options:

1. Bug in the code coverage tool
2. I've faced something similar when my CC tool worked on deffrent version of my dlls.(`Rebuild Solution` solved the problem in this case)
3. At least one of your tests calls those methods directly.
4. At least one of your tests calls those methods indirectly: Through inheritance, composition
   and etc...

To understand the reason I offer you to follow:

[image]

If you want to see the coverage from specific test class it's very easy:

1. In "Test Explorer" right click -> Group By -> Class
2. Select the class you want to monitor.
3. Right click -> Analyze Code Coverage For Selected Tests.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

- internal Dispose can be called during finalization, so it may happen.
- Stop() can be called by PerformTimerCancellationCheck->RunTimer->Start-> Start_sets_is_running
- StartAsync apparently not calling.

Detecting code coverage is non-trivial, considering various [optimizations and code generation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159523.aspx). I would probably tolerate 10%-20% error from the analyzer and prefer to focus on checking whether the class really works. Code coverage actually shows that the the block is "visited" not that everything in it works as expected. But of course if the block is not visited at all, that's the problem.

Comment: I'm not following you on the `Stop()` call. Where does the `PerformTimerCancellationCheck->RunTimer` piece exist?

Comment: `await PerformTimerCancellationCheck(interval, numberOfFires);` in `...Task RunTimer(Task task, Tuple<Actio...`

Comment: Ah, I had totally missed that. Alright, so I'm clear on everything except the `StartAsync()` method which isn't ever called. Do you think that's just a bug in the analysis?

Comment: Updated my OP. I turned on code highlights as mentioned in the article and it shows the `Stop()` method not being included in any coverage pass.